# Depending on a Spring project from a non-Spring project

Tags: java, spring

I've got two Java applications that I have to combine. One is Spring, and methods within it need to be called by the second, an Elasticsearch plugin (that I don't think can be turned into a Spring app as it already uses some form of Guice for dependency injection).

The Spring class I need to call looks like:

```
@Component
public class DataServiceController {

    //This is defined within a @Config
    @Autowired
    DataTypesMap dataTypesMap;

    /**
     * Create an item in the data platform
     */
    public ItemCreatedResponse createItem(String data, String dataType)
            throws IOException {
        ProcessStrategy dataStrategy = dataTypesMap.get(dataType);
        return dataStrategy.add(data);
    }
```

If I just add this project as a Maven dependency within the ES plugin, the Autowired `dataTypesMap` is always null (which is to be expected as nothing in the Elasticsearch plugin will be telling it how to autowire).

What can I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a setter method for your autowired fields, then sets the value.

```
@autowired
public void setDataTypesMap (DataTypesMap  dataTypesMap ){
 this.dataTypesMap = dataTypesMap ;
}
```

In your application you can not autowired the bean, but you can set it.

```
myBean.setDataTypeMap();
```

The second option is initiate a the context of the spring application inside the non-spring application.

You can see how to do it here.

http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-creating-a-spring-application.html